# JavaScript Double Click Card

Tags: javascript

This is a memory card game that I am doing I hope it can be successful.
How can I make it so I can't click more than once in a card?
Why isn't it working?

```js
var board = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
var firstcard = true;
var num1, pos1
var num2, pos2
var good1 = 0;
var bad1 = 0;
var lockboard = false



function shuffle(num) {
  for (i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    n1 = parseInt(Math.random() * 10); // posição 1
    n2 = parseInt(Math.random() * 10); // posição 2
    temp = board[n1]; // 3ª var
    board[n1] = board[n2];
    board[n2] = temp;
  }
}

function hide(id) {
  document.getElementById("c" + id).style.backgroundImage = "url(imagens/capa.jpg)";

}


function play(id) {
  document.getElementById("c" + id).style.backgroundImage = "url('imagens/" + tabuleiro[id] + ".jpg')";

  if (firstcard == true) {
    num1 = tabuleiro[id];
    pos1 = id;
    removeEventListener('firstclick')
    else {
      num2 = tabuleiro[id];
      pos2 = id;
    }

    if (firstcard == false)


      if (num1 == num2) {
        good1 = good1 + 1;
        document.getElementById('good').innerHTML = good1;

        if (good1 == 5)
          document.getElementById('next').style.visibility = "visible";
        if (good1 == 5)
          alert("Nivel Completo. Prossiga para o próximo")
      }
    else {
      bad1 = bad1 + 1;

      setTimeout('hide(' + pos1 + ')', 500);
      setTimeout('hide(' + pos2 + ')', 500);
      document.getElementById('bad').innerHTML = bad1;


    }


    firstcard = !firstcard;

  }
```

If you have any suggestions to add I would consider them thankfully and open mind.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please include that you have researched. If you haven't, I strongly suggest you do that now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and the [`dlbclick event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/dblclick_event) to handle double clicks

```js
var id = 1;
document.getElementById("c" + id).addEventListener('dblclick', function () {
  this.classList.toggle('dblclick');
});
```

```css
.card { 
  padding: 1em; 
  background: #ddd;
  width: 5em;
  height: 8em;
  user-select: none;
}
.card.dblclick {
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div id="c1" class="card">
  <h3>A card</h3>
  <p>Double click me</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The title of the question seems to be misleading. What I believe Rajesh wants, is to force the user to only be able to click once on a card.

How about using a [data-*](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp)?

```
var id = 1;
function init(){
    // You probably want querySelectorAll and a loop here to add events to all cards
    document.getElementById("c" + id).addEventListener('click', clickCard);
}


function clickCard() {
    if (this.getAttribute("data-firstTime") == null){
        this.setAttribute("data-firstTime", "done");
        console.log("do normal game stuff, first time this card is clicked!");
    }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init);
```

Comment: i have tried the code but it wont hide back the card

Comment: Plus when  I define the var id=1; it adds the score. because the id is the number of the image

Comment: If you want to hide the card, you can simply add a "else" to the clickCard function.
    }else{
  this.style.backgroundImage = "url(imagens/capa.jpg)";
 }

However, I just re-read your question and it seems like I misunderstood what you needed. You want to be able to click on a card, see the content, but then have to click on ANOTHER card (and not the same one), right?